# Find What or who am I?

Tags: riddle

> Each day many people from all over the world come and visit me, however they usually only stay for a few minutes.
>
> I am considered by many to be very dirty yet few people would want to live without me.
>
> whenever people come see me, they reveal to me a part of themselves that they rarely show to others.

```
  What or who am I?
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are

> a TOILET, of course.

*Each day many people from all over the world come and visit me, however they usually only stay for a few minutes.*

> People go to the toilet every day, but they usually only spend a few minutes doing their business.

*I am considered by many to be very dirty yet few people would want to live without me.*

> Toilets are dirty, but you'd have problems without one.

*whenever people come see me, they reveal to me a part of themselves that they rarely show to others.*

> Their bottom.

Comment: There we go, Rand al'Thor answering questions in demoralizingly quick time!

Comment: @Phylyp I was lucky with this one - just happened to check the front page half a minute after it was posted.

Comment: Seeing as your answer was posted within a minute, that gives you about half a minute to have figured it out. Somehow, that just ends up making me feel worse 